# Counting Pixels

Tags: java, web, colors

I need to create an application that can count pixels by color and generate a report grouping the counts .
I have found an open source application - ImageMagic , that can generate a file with Hex code of color and pixel .

I now need to group by shades of similar color and report -- in particular, I need to report all shades of yellow and all shades of brown.

I am using a small Java code  and compareTo method to do this but the challenge is setting up the shade range 
Does the Hex code follow a standard pattern so that I can define a range ?
I understand  picking "shades of color" is subjective but I need to know if I start from white and move all the way to end of yellow, does the hex code follow an order ?

Comment: Search SO & try some stuff first, Might can have look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524196/java-get-pixel-array-from-image

Comment: The link I included gives you an idea of how hex colors are formed. It is not a full solution as you will have to determine what becomes "brown", "blue", etc. As you will see in the link, the hex codes are RGB values. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239803/how-does-hexadecimal-color-work

Comment: You may want to group colors based on distance to eachother, using the R, G, and B elements like they are X/Y/Z coordinates, it isn't foolproof though