# Why there are so many color values for HTML like (RGB, HEX, HSL, RGBA, HSLA)?

Tags: html, css, colors, rgb, color-picker

I am a beginner at HTML and CSS. Why are there are so many color values if each of them can be used for a particular color?

Comment: you search about each type, you understand how it works, you compare all them, you read a bit of history about each one, etc --> you have you answer

Comment: @Temani Afif k! gonna do that.

Comment: Consider the fact that computers have proportions of red, green and blue of a pixel under their control, yet humans prefer perceptually-based colour systems. This would be a nice supplement to Temani's suggestion.

Comment: Why the -1 in the answer? It would be cool if you could give a good reason to that.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, all of them use different properties, so you have the power to choose whatever is convenient to you.

- RGB = Red, Green and Blue amount from 0 to 255;
- HEX = A shorter version of the RGBs amount, you can see how it works here: [How does hexadecimal color work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239803/how-does-hexadecimal-color-work);
- HSL = Hue (0 to 360), Saturation and Lightness (both 0 to 100), example: https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_hsl.asp (I don't like to quote w3schools but you'll get the point there as well) - basically the first it's the color, second how strong it is, third how light or dark it is;
- RGBA = Same of RGB but it'll include and extra value for Alpha, which is the transparency;
- Same = Same of HSL but with the Alpha channel mentioned on RGBA as well.