# Use of # in HEX color format

Tags: javascript

What does # mean in the following code?

```
function rndm_colour(){
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color
}
```

Comment: It's creating a random colour in the HEX color format, which requires a `#` as a prefix

Comment: This question does not show any effort to convey what you have *actually* tried? [Similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239803/how-does-hexadecimal-color-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code creates a random color in the HEX format. All HEX colors always start with a "#".

- For more info:

  - [Wikipedia - Web Colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors)
  - [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_hexadecimal.asp)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this function generates a random [HTML Color code](https://htmlcolorcodes.com/), which begins with a `#`.