# Change background color in Qliksense

Tags: background, qliksense, anychart

I need to change the background color of certain columns based on a numeric value, and I can't find a way to properly do it.
In the uploaded image there's a more detailed example of what I'd need

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Edit:
Here's the image, not sure how but it didn't get linked right the first time

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJHZ7.jpg

Comment: Could you please add the image as well? :P

Comment: Done. The link was there, but couldn't be seen because of formatting

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your screenshot what you actually desire, but you can always do conditional coloring in most Qlik charts. I can't speak from experience about AnyChart objects but it [appears from their documentation](https://qlik.anychart.com/extensions/anygantt/docs/project/#color-by-expression) that you can also use conditional coloring with their extensions.

Here's a simple example where the color red, via the [`Red()` color function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/ColorFunctions/color-functions-charts.htm#anchor-1), is applied where the **[WeekDayNumField]** is `1`:

```
=if(Num(WeekDayNumField) = 1, red())
```

Basically, all Mondays will turn red, based on my default [`Weekday()` settings](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/DateAndTimeFunctions/weekday.htm). Here's what that may look like (note that I'm using a Qlik pivot table object):

[image: Screenshot of a Qlik Sense pivot table with basic conditional coloring]

You could also pre-define some color values in the Data Load Editor (here, I'm using [color hex values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239803/how-does-hexadecimal-color-work)):

```
[Day Colors]:
load * inline [
DayColor    ,   WeekDayNumField
#c3e694     ,   0
#ca8d8a     ,   1
#7d90f6     ,   2
#a97cd9     ,   3
#a97cd9     ,   4
#8fdfe6     ,   5
#8fdfe6     ,   6
];
```

Then when creating a conditional coloring expression, you could use something like this:

```
=if(Sum(Expression1) > 20000, DayColor)
```

That expression allows us to base our coloring off of the result of an aggregation while keeping the resulting colors consistent with the days of the week:

[image: Screenshot of a Qlik Sense pivot table with more basic conditional coloring]